# One of my nav-pills is not working

Tags: php, html, nav-pills

```
<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap1">Cap.1 - Componenta gospodariei</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.2<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap2a">Cap2a - Terenuri in proprietate</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap2b">Cap2b - Identificarea pe parcele</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap3">Cap.3 - Modul de utilizare al suprafetelor</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.4<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4a">Cap4a - Suprafata arabil. pe raza loc.</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4a1">Cap4a1 - Supraf. cultivata in sere si solarii</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4b1">Cap4b1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4b2">Cap4b2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4c">Cap4c - Supraf. cultivata cu legume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.5<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5a">Cap5a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5b">Cap5b</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5c">Cap5c</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5d">Cap5d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap6">Cap.6 - Suprafete efectiv irigate in camp</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap7">Cap.7 - Animale domestice si/sau salbatice</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap8">Cap.8 - Evolutia efectivelor de animale</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap9">Cap.9 - Utilaje, instal. pt. agric. si silvic. </a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.10<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap10a">Cap10a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap10b">Cap10b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap11">Cap.11 - Constructii existente</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap12">Cap.12 - Atestate de producator</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap13">Cap.13 - Mentiuni proceduri succesorale</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap14">Cap.14 - Inregistrari privind preemptiunile</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.15<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap15a">Cap15a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap15b">Cap15b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-9"> 
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cap1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <?php include('view_cap1.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap2a" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap2a.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap2b" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap2b.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include ('view_cap3.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap4a" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap4a.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap4a1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap4a1.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap4b1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap4b1.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap4b2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap4b2.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap4c" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap4c.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap5a" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap5a.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap5b" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap5b.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap5c" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap5c.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap5d" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap5d.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap6" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap6.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap7" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap7.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap8" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap8.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap9" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap9.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap10a" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap10a.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap10b" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap10b.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap11" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap11.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap12" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap12.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap13" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap13.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap14" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap14.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap15a" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap15a.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="cap15b" class="tab-pane fade">
      <?php include('view_cap15b.php');?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ok, so I have the code above and it is working except where it says "cap3". When I hit the cap3 pill nothing appear in the tab content and I couldn't see what is wrong in my code. I posted it here, maybe someone can see better than me.

Comment: put that aslo inside `<li class="dropdown"><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul><li>`

Comment: Like this:- `<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.3<span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap3">Cap.3 - Modul de utilizare al suprafetelor</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a jsFiddle of that is working. The only difference is I swapped out the PHP include with a string.

```
<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap1">Cap.1 - Componenta gospodariei</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.2<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap2a">Cap2a - Terenuri in proprietate</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap2b">Cap2b - Identificarea pe parcele</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap3">Cap.3 - Modul de utilizare al suprafetelor</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.4<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4a">Cap4a - Suprafata arabil. pe raza loc.</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4a1">Cap4a1 - Supraf. cultivata in sere si solarii</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4b1">Cap4b1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4b2">Cap4b2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap4c">Cap4c - Supraf. cultivata cu legume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.5<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5a">Cap5a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5b">Cap5b</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5c">Cap5c</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap5d">Cap5d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap6">Cap.6 - Suprafete efectiv irigate in camp</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap7">Cap.7 - Animale domestice si/sau salbatice</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap8">Cap.8 - Evolutia efectivelor de animale</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap9">Cap.9 - Utilaje, instal. pt. agric. si silvic. </a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.10<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap10a">Cap10a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap10b">Cap10b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap11">Cap.11 - Constructii existente</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap12">Cap.12 - Atestate de producator</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap13">Cap.13 - Mentiuni proceduri succesorale</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap14">Cap.14 - Inregistrari privind preemptiunile</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cap.15<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap15a">Cap15a</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cap15b">Cap15b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-9"> 
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cap1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="cap2a" class="tab-pane fade">
      2a
    </div>
    <div id="cap2b" class="tab-pane fade">
      2b
    </div>
    <div id="cap3" class="tab-pane fade">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="cap4a" class="tab-pane fade">
      4a
    </div>
    <div id="cap4a1" class="tab-pane fade">
      4a1
    </div>
    <div id="cap4b1" class="tab-pane fade">
      4b1
    </div>
    <div id="cap4b2" class="tab-pane fade">
      4b2
    </div>
    <div id="cap4c" class="tab-pane fade">
      4c
    </div>
    <div id="cap5a" class="tab-pane fade">
      5a
    </div>
    <div id="cap5b" class="tab-pane fade">
      5b
    </div>
    <div id="cap5c" class="tab-pane fade">
      5c
    </div>
    <div id="cap5d" class="tab-pane fade">
      5d
    </div>
    <div id="cap6" class="tab-pane fade">
      6
    </div>
    <div id="cap7" class="tab-pane fade">
      7
    </div>
    <div id="cap8" class="tab-pane fade">
      8
    </div>
    <div id="cap9" class="tab-pane fade">
     9
    </div>
    <div id="cap10a" class="tab-pane fade">
      10a
    </div>
    <div id="cap10b" class="tab-pane fade">
      10b
    </div>
    <div id="cap11" class="tab-pane fade">
      11
    </div>
    <div id="cap12" class="tab-pane fade">
      12
    </div>
    <div id="cap13" class="tab-pane fade">
      13
    </div>
    <div id="cap14" class="tab-pane fade">
      14
    </div>
    <div id="cap15a" class="tab-pane fade">
      15a
    </div>
    <div id="cap15b" class="tab-pane fade">
      15b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/372qpps2/

I did notice your include for #3 does have a space between it and the bracket which the other lines don't have. I don't believe this would make a difference but you can try it.

Based on the working example I would say your issue is with the code in view_cap3.php.

Comment: Thank you for showing me that my code is working. I found that my "header.php" included at the begining had this line <li><a href="view_cap3.php" id="cap3">Cap3</a></li>. I deleted the "id=cap 3" and now it is working.